# Arduino IDE falied to connect Blynk USB

Tags: arduino-uno, blynk

Im using Arduino IDE to connect blink cloud with my Smartphone, but when I run the tools> Blynk > Run USB script I receive the flowing message:

```
socat[11716] E SSL_connect(): error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find how to solve this problem (Only for studies propose). In Arduino Home folder, I go to libraries->Blynk->scripts, I open the blynk-ser.sh in a text editor and search for line when socat is used, i find this

```
socat $GEN_ATTR "$FROM_ATTR" "$TO_ATTR"
```

So, I change to

```
socat $GEN_ATTR "$FROM_ATTR" "$TO_ATTR",verify=0
```

This issue is because in the certs folder client.pem is missing, I dont find how to generate this, but, I avoid ssl validation for the connection.

WARN: DO NOT USE THIS TIP IN PRODUCTION, BECAUSE YOU WILL MAKE YOUR PROJECT UNSAFE